# If I check in eclipse project into tfs, will I be able to use it in VS environment?

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, tfs, migration

My ultimate goal is to completely migrate eclipse (mars) project into Visual Studio environment.

During my research, I have tried several options:

1) Create project from existing code. Doesn't apply to my case, since my project is a combination of .java and .jsp files, wizard only offers C++, C#, Visual Basic options.

2) TFS plugin for eclipse.

3) Checking in the project from eclipse into tfs.

Within the third option, I am planning to create a new team project, and check in the project from eclipse based on that [article manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568708(v=vs.120).aspx).

My question is **will I be able to open and operate project I checked in inside VS environment**?

I am also opened to any other suggestion, which might help me resolve that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an Eclipse project and you want to move to something like Visual Studio there are three options:

- [Java Language Support plugin](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bc561769-36ff-4a40-9504-e266e8706f93)
- [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com)
- [Java Language Service for Android and Eclipse Android Project Import](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/53e6e65b-fa0f-411a-a98d-7911009537ac)

Except for the latest, I expect you have to review the build script to make it work in the new environment.

TFS/VSTS is language agnostic and has no interested in IDE and has no "project conversion" support.

Comment: It's really a pity there is no direct way of doing so. But thanks for the links, I will make sure to study all of these options.

Answer (score 1):

No, sharing(check in) the project in Team Foundation server just means to source control the code. You can't directly using them in VS environment.

However you can download the project and work on it locally(local eclipse). Then check in the changes to TFS server. More details please refer: [Importing Projects from Team Foundation Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568707(v=vs.120).aspx)

> Here is a tutorial includes step-by-step instructions to help you get
>   started with the Team Foundation Server plug-in for Eclipse.
>
> [Team Foundation Server Plug-in for Eclipse - Beginner's Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh913026%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)